# Ruby testing: block vs. method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

As I've been writing test suites for a Rails app, I've noticed that there are two different ways to create tests, a `test` block and a regular method:

```
test "the truth" do
  assert true
end
```

vs.

```
def test_for_something_else
  assert true
end
```

Is there any difference between the two testing structures? When should I use one over the other?

**Edit:** On further inspection, tests written as methods are counted in `rake:stats` while those written with the `test` syntax are not. There's one difference…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the block syntax was added due to the popularity of Behaviour-Driven-Development frameworks such as RSpec, with their more natural *Should do X...* syntax. In the end it's a matter of personal preference.

- I blogged about [how it's implemented](http://johntopley.com/2009/01/10/the-power-and-beauty-of-ruby) a while ago.

Comment: Cool. I'm assuming Rails just hasn't modified the rake:stats code to account for the newer syntax, then.

Comment: That's right. There's been a ticket open for it since last February: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1915-rake-stats-bad-method-count

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that technically there is no difference between the two. The former allows you to use a string to describe your test, whereas with the latter form you have to come up with a descriptive method name which are sometimes annoyingly long and hard to read [1]. Because of this difference I would personally prefer the former, but in the end it's down to personal / project preference.

[1] `"add two interleaving timers that trigger in the opposite order"` vs. `test_addTwoInterleavingTimersThatTriggerInTheOppositeOrder(...)`

Answer (score 0):

One difference/annoyance I have found is in Vim with Ctags and the TagList plugin. If your tests are not written as functions you can't quickly browse them using the `:TlistToggle` command. If you have a lot of tests in one file this can make quickly navigating them more difficult.